# Microsoft Access 2007 date AND time picker?

Tags: ms-access, datepicker, ms-access-2007

Hi i have a text box that needs to be populated with the date AND time so that when a user click on the text box the calender will pop up and when the user clicks the date the date and time will be put into the text box.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Active-X controls, there is a Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control.

Caution though.  If you use this you may run into problems if a workstation doesn't have the .ocx installed or if you have users with different versions of Access.  One thing that can happen is that if a workstation doesn't have the .ocx installed and it opens the database, it will un-check the reference to the active-x control.  Then when anyone else opens the database they will see a blank spot where the control should be.

Answer (score 0):

In your text-box property, set the [Format] to a Date-related option, for example "Short Date", also make sure that the [Show Date Picker] is set to "For dates", then you are ready to go...